# How to get amount of non-ACK-ed TCP data for the socket?

Tags: networking, sockets, tcp

Linux has ioctl SIOCOUTQ described in man-page tcp(7) that returns amount of unsent data in socket buffers. If I understand kernel code right, all the non-ACKed data is counted as "unsent". The ioctl is available at least since 2.4.x.

Is there anything alike for {Free,Net,Open,*}BSD, Solaris, Windows?

Comment: No, Linux-only TCP_INFO was acceptable for me.

Answer (score 10):

There are (at least) two different pieces of information you might want: the amount of data that hasn't been sent yet, and the amount of data that's been sent-but-not-ACK-ed.

On Linux: `SIOCOUTQ` is documented to give the amount of unsent data, but actually gives the sum of (unsent data + sent-but-not-ACK-ed data). A [recent patch (Feb 2016)](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/582097/) made it possible to get the actual unsent data from the `tcpi_notsent_bytes` field in the `TCP_INFO` struct.

On macOS and iOS: `getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NWRITE, ...)` is just like `SIOCOUTQ`: it's documented to give the amount of unsent data, but actually gives the sum of (unsent data + sent-but-not-ACK-ed data). I don't know any way to get more fine-grained information.

On Windows: [`GetPerTcpConnectionEStats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb485738(VS.85).aspx) with the `TcpConnectionEstatsSendBuff` option gives you both unsent data and sent-but-not-ACK-ed data [as two separate numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee720200(v=vs.85).aspx).

I don't know how to get this information on other operating systems.

Comment: Has anybody got GetPerTcpConnectionEStats() reading TcpConnectionEstatsSendBuff to work on Windows? I have tried it, but I do not get reasonable values. I guess, this information must be explicitly enabled, but when I try to enable it using SetPerTcpConnectionEStats(), I get an access denied error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since TCP/IP is implemented as a stream device, it might be possible to take a kernel dive and get the queue->q_count (number of bytes on the queue).

Comment: Of course it's possible to patch kernel and get required information. I was wondering about some existing API.