# Why does TCP not tell me how many bytes have been received?

Tags: sockets, tcp, posix

When sending data on a TCP connection, the TCP stack makes sure the bytes arrive, and lost packets are resent as needed. To accomplish that, the other end sends ACK messages to acknowledge it has received the data.

As the TCP stack receives ACK messages, it knows that the other end has received some data and can stop retransmitting. While it doesn't know exactly how much data the other end has received (ACKs may get lost or delayed) it at least has a lower bound of data that has already been received on the other end.

To my knowledge, TCP implementations don't make that information available to high level callers.

Specifically I'm thinking of the POSIX socket APIs, as far as I know there's no way to tell how much data the other end has received. I only know how much I sent, but due to large buffer sizes it could take a lot of time for that data to be received.

Obviously, if I control the other end, I could occasionally report how much data has been received with explicit messages (either on the same tcp connection or via a separate channel), but that seems inelegant.

Why is that information not exposed to the user? It would be useful for things like progress bars.

Comment: TCP ACK gives only the information what is received by the OS. It does not say anything what is actually read by the peer application and especially not what was processed by the peer application. But in my opinion this application level information is what is actually needed in your progress bar example.

Comment: Apart from that some OS (indirectly) provide the information you want - see [How to get amount of non-ACK-ed TCP data for the socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595426/how-to-get-amount-of-non-ack-ed-tcp-data-for-the-socket).

Comment: The value returned by `recv()` tells you how many bytes have been received *by your application*, and your application is free to send that data back to the client if you want.  TCP doesn't tell you how many bytes have been received *by the network stack* (or by the network card, or the local router, or any of the other routers between you and the other program) because that information is considered to be an implementation detail that is better abstracted away so that programs don't rely on it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's a good point. My use case idea was to use the information for an upload progress bar, assuming that once the data is ACKed it's "uploaded". But it may just sit in a different buffer waiting to be written to a slow disk, so reporting the data as "uploaded" may be a bit premature.